# Cannot invoke 'schema' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm having trouble converting some Objective C to Swift.

```
iCloudSchemaDatabase *sdb = [self schema: @"33"];
```

I can't figure out what the problem is, I've had various attemps and have searched for why, I obviously need to pass a string, but nothing works...

```
var x = self.iCloudDBDelegate.schema("")

let sdb = self.iCloudDBDelegate.schema("33")
```

Schema come from an Objective C protocol

```
@protocol iCloudDBDelegate<NSObject>

@required
@property (weak,nonatomic) id<iCloudDBDelegate>iCloudDBDelegate;

@optional
-(iCloudSchemaDatabase*)schema:(NSString*)calledBy;

@end
```

The protocol added this to my swift file.

```
public var iCloudDBDelegate: iCloudDBDelegate!
```

Comment: Did you try to pass `NSString` rather than `String`?

Comment: No just something between double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer, very surprised...

```
let sdb = iCloudDBDelegate!.schema!("33")
```

Comment: That's two chances to crash. Don't blindly force-unwrap optionals. Do it safely.

Comment: Thats the only way it would compile.

Comment: What about using `if let sdb = iCloudDBDelegate?.schema?("33") { // do something }`

Comment: Does it or doesn't it? And if it does, what's the error?

Comment: Oh sorry, no thats fine thanks, I must have copied something else, hmmm.

Comment: It's worth understanding why this is true: `schema` is an `@optional` method. It may not be implemented. That's expressed in Swift as an `Optional` and the usual rules for that apply.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call the `schema` method without handling:

1. The case when the delegate property is `nil`
2. The case when the delegate doesn't implement the `schema` method (since it is optional to do so).

Gracefully handling both would look something like this:

```
//       because `schema` may not be implemented 
//                                            | 
//       because the delegate may be `nil`    | 
//                                    |       | 
//                                    v       v 
if let schemaResult = iCloudDBDelegate?.schema?("33") {
    // do something with the result of calling schema
} else {
    // either the delegate is `nil` or it doesn't implement `schema`.
}
```